# Suppress vertical space above and below array?

Tags: spacing, arrays

The `array` environment uses `\arraystretch` (and `\extrarowheight` if the `array` package is loaded) to add "leading" between the rows of the `array`.  In addition, this vertical space is added above the first row and below the last row.

Is there a way to suppress the space above the first row and below the last row while still preserving the inter-row space of the `array`?

Compare the output using `myarray` and `mysolidarray` (which sets `\arraystretch` to `0`) as defined in the following code.  I am looking for something in between the two.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{myarray}%
  {\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}}%
  {\end{array}}

\newenvironment{mysolidarray}%
  {%
    \def\arraystretch{0}%
    \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  }%
  {\end{array}}

\begin{document}
\fboxsep=0pt
\begin{tabular}{l}
\verb|$P + Q$|: \fbox{$P + Q$}
\\
\verb|myarray|:
\fbox{$
  \begin{myarray}
    P + Q
  \end{myarray}
$}
\fbox{$
  \begin{myarray}
    P + {} \\ Q
  \end{myarray}
$}
\\
\verb|mysolidarray|:
\fbox{$
  \begin{mysolidarray}
    P + Q
  \end{mysolidarray}
$}
\fbox{$
  \begin{mysolidarray}
    P + {} \\ Q
  \end{mysolidarray}
$}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Follow up question: [Suppress vertical space above and below array with href](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614856/suppress-vertical-space-above-and-below-array-with-href)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can measure the array typesetting it twice, first for getting the height of the first row, then for the depth of the last row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{mysolidarray}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\arraystretch{0}%
  \extrarowheight=\z@
  \sbox\z@{$\begin{array}[t]{#1}\BODY\end{array}$}%
  \sbox\tw@{$\begin{array}[b]{#1}\BODY\end{array}$}%
  \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter
  \firstlineheight\the\ht\expandafter\z@\expandafter
  \lastlinedepth\the\dp\tw@\relax
  \sbox{\solidarraybox}{$\begin{array}[t]{#1}\BODY\end{array}\m@th$}
  \ht\solidarraybox=\firstlineheight
  \dp\solidarraybox=\dimexpr\dp\solidarraybox-\dp\@arstrutbox+\lastlinedepth\relax
  \box\solidarraybox
}
\makeatother
\newdimen\firstlineheight
\newdimen\lastlinedepth
\newsavebox{\solidarraybox}

\begin{document}
\fboxsep=0pt 
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\verb|$P + Q$| & \fbox{$P + Q$}
\\
\verb|array|&
\fbox{$
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    P + Q
  \end{array}
$}
\fbox{$
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    P + {} \\ Q
  \end{array}
$}
&\extrarowheight=2pt
\fbox{$
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    P + Q
  \end{array}
$}
\fbox{$
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
    P + {} \\ Q
  \end{array}
$}
\\
\verb|mysolidarray|&
\fbox{$
  \begin{mysolidarray}{@{}l@{}}
    P + Q
  \end{mysolidarray}
$}
\fbox{$
  \begin{mysolidarray}{@{}l@{}}
    P + {} \\ Q
  \end{mysolidarray}
$}
&\extrarowheight=2pt
\fbox{$
  \begin{mysolidarray}{@{}l@{}}
    P + Q
  \end{mysolidarray}
$}
\fbox{$
  \begin{mysolidarray}{@{}l@{}}
    P + {} \\ Q
  \end{mysolidarray}
$}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A bit hacky, but it deserved an upvote just for the chain of `\expandafter`s (I’m especially delighted by `...\the\ht\expandafter\z@...`)!

Answer (score 1):

You mean something `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{-1pt}` ?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{myarray}%
  { \setlength{\extrarowheight}{-1pt}
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}}%
  {\end{array}}

\newenvironment{mysolidarray}%
  {%
    \def\arraystretch{0}%
    \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  }%
  {\end{array}}

\begin{document}
\fboxsep=0pt
\begin{tabular}{l}
\verb|$P + Q$|: \fbox{$P + Q$}
\\
\verb|myarray|:
\fbox{$
  \begin{myarray}
    P + Q
  \end{myarray}
$}
\fbox{$
  \begin{myarray}
    P + {} \\ Q
  \end{myarray}
$}
\\
\verb|mysolidarray|:
\fbox{$
  \begin{mysolidarray}
    P + Q
  \end{mysolidarray}
$}
\fbox{$
  \begin{mysolidarray}
    P + {} \\ Q
  \end{mysolidarray}
$}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't quite do what I want.  First, it affects all rows -- compare the normal inter-row spacing with the inter-row spacing when `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{-1pt}` is used.  Second, it doesn't affect the extra space added after the last row.  Is there some way to use `\extrarowheight` to correct these two deficiencies?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use vertical rules (which is recommended anyway), you can use  `\addlinespace[some value]` from `booktabs` just after the first \hline and before the last \hline of the table to have full control:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newenvironment{myarray}%
  {\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}}%
  {\end{array}}

\newenvironment{mysolidarray}%
  {%
    \def\arraystretch{0}%
    \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  }%
  {\end{array}}

\begin{document}
\fboxsep=0pt
\begin{tabular}{l}
\verb|$P + Q$|: \fbox{$P + Q$}
\\
\verb|myarray|:
\fbox{$
  \begin{myarray}
    P + Q
  \end{myarray}
$}
\fbox{$
  \begin{myarray}
    P + {} \\ Q
  \end{myarray}
$}
\\
\verb|mysolidarray|:
\fbox{$
  \begin{mysolidarray}
    P + Q
  \end{mysolidarray}
$}
\fbox{$
  \begin{mysolidarray}
    P + {} \\ Q
  \end{mysolidarray}
$}
\\[3ex]
\verb|othersolidarray|:
$
 \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}%
 \arrayrulecolor{red}
\hline\addlinespace[-1pt]
 P + Q \\ Q + P
\\
\addlinespace[-1.25pt]
\hline
 \end{array}
$
$
 \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}%
 \arrayrulecolor{red}
\hline\addlinespace[-1pt]
 P + {} \\ Q
\\
\addlinespace[-1.25pt]
\hline
 \end{array}
$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]